# VS Code y Python venv: cómo activar un ambiente virtual?

Tags: python-3.x, linux, vscode, virtualenv

Estoy intentando configurar VS Code para trabajar con Python3 y virtualenv en Linux Mint 19.1.

En mi sistema también está instalada la distribución Anaconda de Python.

Instalé VS Code vía Flatpak y las extensiones: "Python" y "Visual Studio IntelliCode - Preview".

Estoy creando mi ambiente virtual, dentro del directorio del proyecto, así:

`$ python3.6 -m venv venv`

Y lo activo en el **terminal del sistema**, así:

```
$ source venv/bin/python
$ (venv) python -V
Python 3.6.7
```

El problema es que en VS Code "Select Python Interpreter" no aparece esta opción, aparecen otras: Python 2.7, Python 3.5 y Python 3.7 (Anaconda).

Extraño, porque `which` dice que la versión 3.5 no está en el sistema:

```
$ which python2.7 python3.5 python3.6 python3.7 
/usr/bin/python2.7
python3.5 not found
/usr/bin/python3.6
/home/alejandro/anaconda3/bin/python3.7
```

En las configuraciones de "Workspace" de VS Code, definí:

```
"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/venv/bin/python"
```

Pero eso tampoco me habilita a seleccionar el interpretador deseado.

En el **terminal de VS Code**:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.12

$ source venv/bin/activate
$ (venv) python -V
Python 2.7.12
$ (venv) which python
/usr/bin/python
$ (venv) file /usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/python: symbolic link to python2
```

La versión debería ser la misma que aparece cuando activo el ambiente virtual en el terminal del sistema.
Si pregunto por la versión que me interesa:

```
$ (venv) which python3.6
which: no python3.6 in (/home/alejandro/path/to/project/venv/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin)
$ (venv) ls venv/bin
activate  activate.csh  activate.fish  easy_install  easy_install-3.6  pip  pip3  pip3.6  python  python3  python3.6
```

En definitiva, no sé qué se me está escapando para poder activar el interpretador propio del ambiente virtual. Cualquier sugerencia, se agradece.

**[Editado]**

Intenté un enfoque diferente, esta vez creé el ambiente virtual desde el **terminal de VS Code**:

```
$ python3 -m venv venv
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ (venv) python -V
Python 3.5.2
```

Es una de las opciones que aparece en "Select Python Interpreter" pero que `which` dice que no existe. Además, no aparece como siendo un ambiente virtual a nivel de directorio, sino como un ambiente global (`/usr/bin/python3`).

Cuando voy al **terminal del sistema** y activo el ambiente virtual:

```
$ source venv/bin/activate
$ (venv) python -V
Python 3.6.7
```

Que es la versión que sí está instalado en el sistema, pero que no aparece en la lista de opciones.

Cómo puede ser que, activando el mismo ambiente virtual en dos terminales diferentes, aparezcan dos versiones diferentes de python?

Comment: En mi caso, en macOS funciona poner la carpeta venv en el nivel del proyecto, ojo que no me refiero a moverla, cuando mueves una carpeta con venv o le cambias el nombre deja de funcionar normalmente, sino a crear el entorno virtual a la altura del proyecto que usas, tambien puedes configurarle la carpeta donde esta el venv sobrescribiendo la clave correspondiente en settings https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-environments-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: Sí, estoy creando el directorio en la raíz del proyecto, en el mismo directorio que está `.vscode`.

Comment: Puse el link de visual studio, aca esta el correcto, prueba alguna de estas variantes. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: @YoandreSaavedra, no veo nada diferente de lo que ya he hecho. Teóricamente debería detectar automáticamente el directorio `venv`. Inclusive, en "Select Python Interpreter" dice `current: ./venv/bin/python`. Pero no es eso que aparece en el terminal...

Comment: Probaste tambien poner punto delante asi .venv ?? Tienes razon deberia detectarlo, no te sale en la lista de entornos??

Comment: No, no aparece en la lista. Es raro, porque aparece la versión 3.5, que no está instalada, y no aparece la 3.6 que sí está... En relación al punto delante de `.venv`, no probé, pero eso sería si el directorio `venv` hubiese sido creado como directorio oculto. Voy a probar creándolo como directorio oculto, quién sabe.

Comment: Creé el directorio oculto `.venv`, ninguna diferencia.

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente, el problema estaba relacionado con el hecho de haber instalado VS Code vía **Flatpak**.

Desinstalé e instalé de nuevo usando el instalador `.deb` de la página oficial de VS Code y ahora sí, aparecen correctamente tanto los entornos globales como los virtuales.